# Perl regex pattern match with saved variable

Tags: regex, perl

I need to do pattern match with two variables one contains the string and the other contains the regex pattern 
I tried with the following program

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $name = "sathish.java";
my $other = '*.java';
if ( $name =~ m/$other/ )
{
  print "sathish";

 }
```

kindly help where am missing

Thanks
Sathishkumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Shmuel answer suits your needs, but if you are looking for common way of extract the filename from a complete path name, you can use [File::Basename](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Basename):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename;

my ($name, $path, $suffix) = fileparse("/example/path/test.java", qw/.java/);

print "name: $name\n";  
print "path: $path\n";
print "suffix: $suffix\n";
```

it prints:

```
name: test
path: /example/path/
suffix: .java
```

Comment: Thanks miguel ,But here my problem i will be etting the value from database my pattern will be anything like *,.*,*java so iwill be having this in variable on the fly so i need to check the pattern coming from back end and string

Answer (score 1):

'*.java' is not a valid regex. you probably want to use this code:

```
my $other = '\.java$';
if ($name =~ m/$other/) {
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following style which is more appropriate of your need

```
$other = "*.java";
if ($name =~m/^$other/){}
```

--SJ

Answer (score 0):

I like Shmuel's answer, but I'm guessing you probably want to capture the first part of the regex into variable as well?

if so, use

```
my $other = '\.java$';
if ($name =~ m/(\D*)$other/) {
  print $1;
# prints "sathish"
}
```